# Temp var with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an element that uses both `ng-if` and `ng-options` to bind data, but only show if there are values.  It uses a function call, like so:

```
<select ng-model="a" ng-if="reallyExpensiveCall(variable)" ng-options="text for text in reallyExpensiveCall(variable)">
```

So the issue I have is that I'm making the exact same method call twice.  Is there some way to wrap that `<select>` call in some type of local variable storage so the expensive call only happens once, but then I can use the result in both `ng-if` and `ng-options?`

I should note this is inside of an `ng-repeat="variable in variables"` type 'wrapper'

Comment: You could use `ng-init` to initialize a scope variable, but that would only call once and I don't think it would update on a scope change. Otherwise, you should set it up in the controller and access it from the controller variable. Then you could control what happens on a scope change, etc...

Comment: When will the return value of that call change?  If it is only set once then just call it in your controller and set a scope property to the result.

Answer (score 1):

I would hide the really expensive call behind a service that can make the call asynchronously and cache the result. Then expose an API from the service to update it when and if its necessary.

**Service**

```
app.factory('expensiveOperationStatus', function($q, $timeout) {
    var status = {
        shouldShow: false,
        data: [],
        refresh: refreshAsync
    };

    function refreshAsync() {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          $timeout(function() {
             try {
                var result = ... really expensive operation                   
                // do really expensive operation
                status.shouldShow = result;
                status.data.push({...});
                status.data.push({...});
                status.data.push({...});
                deferred.resolve(result);
             }
             catch (e) {
                deferred.reject(e);
             }  
          });

          return deferred.promise;            
    }


    return status;
});
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, expensiveOperationStatus) {
    $scope.expensiveOperationStatus= expensiveOperationStatus;
    $scope.expensiveOperationStatus.refresh();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="a" ng-if="expensiveOperationStatus.shouldShow" 
        ng-options="text for text in expensiveOperationStatus.data">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the result of the function for that variable:

```
app.controller('whatever', fucntion($scope) {
 var results = {};
 $scope.reallyExpensiveCall = function(variable) {
        //assuming variable is a string...
        if (typeof results[variable] != 'undefined') {
            return results[variable];
        }
        else {
            //do stuff
            results[variable] = result;
            return result;
        }
 }
```